# V8 r package - extract text from html drop down menu (rMarkdown document)

Tags: javascript, html, r, r-markdown

I have simple implementation of html drop down menu in rMarkdown document and I'm using V8 r package for using javascript to do that.

````
---
title: "js + plotly"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
    widescreen: true
    smaller: false
---

## Zero slide

<div>
<select name="newSkill" id="newSkill">
<option value="1">A skill</option>
<option value="2">Another skill</option>
<option value="3">Yet another skill</option>
</select>
</div>


```{r}
library(V8)

ct <- v8()
ct$assign("getFromDrop", JS("(function(){var skillsSelect = document.getElementById('newSkill'); var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text; return(selectedText);})"))
ct$assign("bar", JS("getFromDrop()"))
output <- ct$get("bar")

print(output)

```
````

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong but it doesn't work. I'm getting following error message:

Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  ReferenceError: document is not defined
Calls:  ... get_str_output -> identical -> context_eval -> .Call

Please, could you give me a hint or advice what to change to be working as expected. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to work can work. V8 isn't going to read from the browser session. It instantiates it's own V8 environment.

Comment: I need to extract text from selected item in drop down menu and send it to r variable.

Comment: Is there any way how can I do that?

Comment: switch to using Shiny

Comment: I'd like to avoid shiny, I need use only pure html and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign back to an `R` variable, you will need Shiny or something similar, such as [fiery](https://github.com/thomasp85/fiery) or [jug](https://github.com/Bart6114/jug) or your own custom websocket implementation.  As @hrbrmstr states `V8` is designed to run independently and has no knowledge of the browser environment instantiated either in RStudio viewer or your browser.

If you don't need to assign back to an `R` variable, you could do something like this.

````
---
title: "js + plotly"
author: ""
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  ioslides_presentation:
  widescreen: true
  smaller: false
---

## Zero slide

<div>
<select name="newSkill" id="newSkill" onchange="getFromDrop()">
<option value="1">A skill</option>
<option value="2">Another skill</option>
<option value="3">Yet another skill</option>
</select>
</div>


<script>
  function getFromDrop{
    var skillsSelect = document.getElementById('newSkill');
    var selectedText = skillsSelect.options[skillsSelect.selectedIndex].text;
    return(selectedText);
  }
</script>
```
````

Comment: I need to assign back to an R variable.

Comment: If you need ui and assignment back to R, then you will be limited to `Shiny` or one of the other alternatives that I mentioned.